# Dimension space of modular forms of weight $2k$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

How can I prove that:

> - For a given natural number $k$ the dimension space of modular forms of weight $2k$ is $\lfloor{\frac{k}{6}\rfloor}+1$ if $k \not\equiv 1 \: (\text{mod}\ 6)$ and $\lfloor{\frac{k}{6}\rfloor}$ if $k \equiv 1 \: (\text{mod}\ 6)$

Comment: This presumably means of level 1. Where are you learning about modular forms? Most introductory books that have this statement also prove it...

Answer (score 4):

This is a very standard argument, see e.g. Corollary 2.16 of William Stein's book "Modular Forms: A Computational Approach". This is available as a free e-book; the relevant section is here:

http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/modform/modform/level_one.html#structure-theorem-for-level-1-modular-forms